# Header looks different on different browsers

Tags: reactjs

The header is has different spacing on each browser and on different computers. How can I make it so it looks the same on all. Safari on mac and chrome on pc look good. Chrome and Brave on Mac have issues.

```
    const MenuItem: React.FC<LinkProps & { external?: boolean }> = ({ href, children, external }) => (
      <Link href={href} target={external ? '_blank' : '_self'}>
        <a
          target={external ? '_blank' : '_self'}
          className="cursor-pointer text-2xl md:text-base text-content hover:opacity-70 duration-300"
        >
          {children}
        </a>
      </Link>
    )
    
    const DesktopMenu = () => (
      <div className="hidden lg:flex items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-row gap-8">
          {menuItems.map(({ href, content, external }) => (
            <MenuItem key={content} external={external} href={href} children={content} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="ml-[30px]">
          <SocialMedia />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    
    const Header = () => (
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-6 px-[10%] top-0 left-0 z-50 w-full">
        <Link href="/">
          <div className="cursor-pointer">
            <Icon iconName="logoWithName" />
          </div>
        </Link>
        <DesktopMenu />
        <MobileMenu />
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: Can you include your CSS or mention what CSS framework/library you're using?

Comment: Your HTML/CSS is not compliant is all if you have issues with it displaying correctly across browsers.